# Force images to scale with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I'm making a static parallax webpage with Boostrap, but I'm having a problem with the images not displaying properly.

I have a custom style sheet and for each sub section I have a different images like this:

```
#LM-sub01{
background: url(../img/32-cover.jpg) no-repeat center;
color: #ffffff;
font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
font-weight: 300; 
font-size: 400%;
}
```

In some sections there will onnly be a short paragraph of text that is much smaller than the image size. I want the image to scale to the screen size, but show the compete image.

Comment: So you want a stretched image? Where the aspect ratio isn't constant.

Comment: No, not quiet. For example, the first image is 1920 x 2160. So I want the width to scale to the width of the screen and then the height to scale to the width of the image. So you can see the complete image.

Comment: Yes, but if the original image is 4:3 and the screen is 16:9, then what happens?

Comment: Check out [Backstretch](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/). "a simple jQuery plugin that allows you to add a dynamically-resized, slideshow-capable background image to any page or element"

Comment: Have you tried doing : width:100% on that div box? Then set the parent div to position:relative so that the width of the image div will be 100% of the parent.

Answer (score 1):

You want the container to take the size of the background image whether or not the contents fill the container. There are a few ways of doing this

**Example 1**

Use actual images, position the container `position: relative` to contain any child elements that are positioned absolute, then position the content `position: absolute` with all directions set to 0 and `overflow: auto`

```css
.example {
  position: relative;
}
.example .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/768/" width="100%" />
  <div class="content">
    <h1> Hello World! </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Example 2**

**If** you know that the images will be the same size you can use the padding-bottom trick, because padding-top and padding-bottom  when given percentage values refer to the percentage of the width, this again requires relative and absolute positioning of the container an content respectively. Change padding bottom to suit your aspect ratios.

```css
.example {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1200/768/');
  background-size: cover;
  padding-bottom: 75%;
}
.example .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto
}
.
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <div class="content">
    <h1> Hello World! </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Example 3**

**If** You don't know what size the images will be and you don't want to use the first method, you can use javascript. You cant actually find the height of the background image itself, so you have to do the following.

1. Create a new image from the background image (the browser will only load the image once) for each element.
2. Append the new images to the elements they are related to.
3. Move the new images off the screen so it cant be accessed by the user.
4. Find the computed height of each image (with width set to 100% of the container width)
5. Set the height of each parent element to that of its image.

```js
function scaleToBg(queryString) {
  this.elements = document.querySelectorAll(queryString);
  for (var i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = window.getComputedStyle(this.elements[i], null).getPropertyValue("background-image").replace(/url\(|\)/g, '');
    img.onload = function() {
      this.parentNode.style.height = window.getComputedStyle(this, null).getPropertyValue("height");
    };
    img.className = "scaleToBgImg";
    img.style.cssText = "position:absolute;left:-100%; width:100%;";
    this.elements[i].appendChild(img);
  }
  this.resize = function() {
    this.images = document.querySelectorAll(".scaleToBgImg");
    for (var i = 0; i < this.images.length; i++) {
      this.images[i].parentNode.style.height = window.getComputedStyle(img, null).getPropertyValue("height");
    }
  };
  return this;
}
var scale = scaleToBg(".scaleToBg");
window.onresize = function() {
  scale.resize();
};
```

```css
.scaleToBg {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#scaleToBg1 {
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1200/200/');
}
#scaleToBg2 {
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1200/400/');
}
#scaleToBg3 {
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1200/600/');
}
#scaleToBg4 {
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1200/800/');
}
```

```html
<div class="scaleToBg" id="scaleToBg1"></div>
<div class="scaleToBg" id="scaleToBg2"></div>
<div class="scaleToBg" id="scaleToBg3"></div>
<div class="scaleToBg" id="scaleToBg4"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Background-size:cover;
```

is the best option to rescale the image along with **container Div**

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
  ...Your content goes here...
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
  body {
  /* Location of the image */
  background-image: url(images/background-photo.jpg);

  /* Background image is centered vertically and horizontally at all times */
  background-position: center center;

  /* Background image doesn't tile */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  /* Background image is fixed in the viewport so that it doesn't move when 
     the content's height is greater than the image's height */
  background-attachment: fixed;

  /* This is what makes the background image rescale based
     on the container's size */
  background-size: cover;

  /* Set a background color that will be displayed
     while the background image is loading */
  background-color: #464646;
}
```

**OR**
See link below
http://sixrevisions.com/css/responsive-background-image/

Comment: that was just for understandings